# arcsde topology register issue

Tags: arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, topology, arccatalog, versioning

I am in trouble with the topology in a sde database.

I create a topology in a dataset from arccatalog, after managing to register it as aversion, I try to validate it from arccatalog, it tells me "The topology cannot be validated because it is registered as versioned.". If I don't register it as versioned I cannot start editing in arcmap. What should I do with the topology so that I can validate it and also start editing session.

I am using Arcmap 10.2 and sql server 2008 r2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found what looks to be the solution to this from Thomas Brown at the old [ArcGIS Discussion Forums](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=2&f=59&t=131120):

> Once a topology dataset is register as versioned, you must perform the
>   validation within ArcMap while editing.
>
> Simply add your topology to ArcMap (as the DEFAULT version or any
>   other), add your topology toolbar, start editing and click the
>   validate command.
>
> Once the data is versioned, all modifications are required to take
>   place within an edit operation.